# How do I deallocate cells of a different length from the initial length in a dynamic 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, delete-operator

I'm trying to read names into a 2d dynamic array of 20 rows and where the length of the names is not limited.  The program crashes at the the end with a "heap corruption" error due to a new length being introduced beyond the initial value of 10.  However, the only issue encountered is when I run the loop to delete the aforementioned cells.  Does anyone know how to delete cells of a different length than the initial value? (specifically in this case.) Do I need to make all cells in the array the new length? P.S. I cannot use vectors because this is a homework assignment which prohibits them.

Ok. This is the updated version with @RetiredNinja 's suggested changes.  It runs just fine and I no longer have the "heap corruption" error under any of my previously tested conditions.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>                             // will be used once I write the sort and search functions

char * ReadString();

void main ()
{
bool contMain=true;
const long numNames=20;
long nameAc=0;
char ** ppNames, c;
ppNames=new char* [numNames];
char test;

while(contMain && nameAc<numNames)
{
    ppNames[nameAc]=ReadString();
    test=ppNames[nameAc][0];
    if(test=='\0')
    {
        contMain=false;
        break;
    }
    else;
    nameAc++;
}
for(int i=0; i<nameAc; i++)
    cout<<ppNames[i]<<endl;

// deallocation
for(int i=0; i<nameAc; i++)
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
    delete ppNames [i];
}
delete[] ppNames;
}


char * ReadString()
{
long aSize=10;
long numChars (0);
char * pNames;
char * pTemp;
char c;
pNames=new char [aSize+1];

while((c = cin.get()) != '\n')
    {
        if(numChars >= aSize)
        {
            aSize *= 2;
            pTemp = new char[aSize + 1];
            memcpy(pTemp, pNames, numChars);
            delete[] pNames;
            pNames = pTemp;
            cout << "Array size increased to " << aSize << endl;
        }
        pNames[numChars++] = c;
    }
    pNames[numChars] = '\0'; //end of string
    return pNames;
}
```

Comment: The function ReadString() itself have so much places need to change. e.g pNames = new char[aSize + 1]; pNames = pTemp; this will immediately cause memory leak. and the intention is not clear. Can you organize your code a little bit and post again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of your code doesn't make much sense.  You allocate and delete rather haphazardly often undoing what you did just a few lines earlier.

Try something like this instead:

```
char * ReadString()
{
    long aSize = 10;
    long numChars = 0;
    char * pNames;
    char * pTemp;
    char c;
    pNames = new char[aSize + 1];

    while((c = cin.get()) != '\n')
    {
        if(numChars >= aSize)
        {
            aSize *= 2;
            pTemp = new char[aSize + 1];
            memcpy(pTemp, pNames, numChars);
            delete[] pNames;
            pNames = pTemp;
            cout << "Array size increased to " << aSize << endl;
        }
        pNames[numChars++] = c;
    }
    pNames[numChars] = '\0';//end of string
    return pNames;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I have a few questions about when to delete allocated memory.  Why don't I need to delete pNames and pTemp after declaring them?  Also, will it cause memory leaks with the function you posted?

Comment: So, you have two cases.  One where the array doesn't need to get any bigger.  You allocate that memory and then return the pointer so it can be deleted later.  The second is when the array does grow you allocate a buffer twice as big assigned to `pTemp`, copy the data from `pNames`, delete `pNames` then assign `pTemp to `pNames` then return it to be deleted later.

Comment: As long as you're matching one `new` to one `delete` you shouldn't have any leaks.  The only issue with a function like this is you're counting on whoever called it to delete that memory later.

Comment: Ohhhh ok. That makes a lot more sense now. So when I delete ppNames in the main function, it also deletes the pNames returned from ReadString as well as pTemp because it is using addresses identical to pNames?

Comment: Yes, the important thing is that somewhere you delete the memory using a pointer that points to it, it doesn't have to be the same pointer.

Comment: It's all starting to come together in my head now. I know these are probably rudimentary questions but your help is greatly appreciated and has been a tremendous help. You're awesome.